# In R, I want to pull out the minimum value of z when x and y are duplicates

Tags: dataframe, datatable, duplicates, subset, minimum

## **In R, I want to pull out the minimum value of z when x and y are duplicates.**

line       x        y     z
3559 1284283 10315402 20995
3560 1284283 10315402 20982
3596 1284341 10315344 20995
3597 1284341 10315344 20982
3633 1284399 10315286 20995
3634 1284399 10315286 20982

### I did this so far:

### identify duplicate x,y locations in the zone, creates a logical vector

### I added the logical vector to the dataframe in column 4

z1_repeat_xy <- duplicated(df_Zone1[,1:2])

df_Zone1$repeat_xy <- z1_repeat_xy # feeds the true or false value to a new column called repeat_xy.

```
 line#       x        y     z repeat_xy
135161 1283668 10314903 19994     FALSE
135164 1283726 10314845 19994     FALSE
135167 1283784 10314787 19994     FALSE
135170 1283842 10314729 19994     FALSE
135171 1283842 10314729 19981      TRUE
135172 1283842 10314729 19968      TRUE
```

### now I want the *minumum* z value corresponding to TRUE values in the 4th column along with the rows containing FALSE

---

### I create a new df with only TRUE values in the repeat column

df_repeats <- filter(df_zone1, repeat_xy == TRUE)

### Created the test_max and test_min df using the ave() function
seems to do what I want. Gives the min or max z value for repeat xy values.

test_max <- df_repeats[df_repeats$z == ave(df_repeats$z, df_repeats$x , FUN =max),]

test_min <- df_repeats[df_repeats$z == ave(df_repeats$z, df_repeats$x , FUN =min),]

write.table(test_max, file = "test_max.txt", sep = " ", row.names = FALSE)

write.table(test_min, file = "test_min.txt", sep = " ", row.names = FALSE)
[image: file test_max]

Comment: I have used the ave() function and it seems to do the trick.

Comment: The z values due not continue to repeat. There are over 25,000 rows in this file.